# How to add some Spring attributes when the application starts

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, internationalization

I am new to Spring framework and I am working on a web application that must be multilanguage.

The tanslated values are in the database and I don't want that each time I am rendering a view to pick the values from the database.

The idea is to get them somewhere from the application. So, I want to load this values when my application starts and I don't know where exactly and where to put them.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I created a bean in spring like this:

```
public class DictionaryAccessor implements ServletContextAware, InitializingBean{

    @Resource
    private DictionaryServices dictionaryServices;

    protected ServletContext context;
    @Override
    public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
        context = servletContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        logger.debug("initializing dictionary");
        loadDictionary();
        logger.debug("done with dictionary");
    }
```

The `DictionaryAccessor` will be loaded when my application starts. In the method `loadDictionary` I put my values as attributes in the `ServletContext` object.

In my jsps, I created my own tag and access the translation or in .zul files I accessed a function from my tld.

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach to this problem is to have a .properties file for your messages, one for each language, either letting the framework decide using the browser's locale which one to use, or specify it directly.

See the reference [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-localeresolver) for locale support in Spring MVC and two different examples [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-internationalization-example/) and [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2010/07/spring-3-mvc-internationalization-i18n-localization-tutorial-example.html).

If you insist on using a database for your i18n data, it is also possible of course but to my knowledge there is no built-in support for this. See [this](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?31015-i18n-and-the-database) thread though for ideas.